# How can I add a realistic metallic texture to this node setup?

Tags: texturing, node-editor, photorealism

[image: NodeSetup]

So here is my node setup for a model i want to animate. Ive added a diffuse,bump, and specular map already but i have one last metallic texture i want to add but there are no tutorials online to help me add it, much less with this setup. Please let me know how i can do this.

Comment: What do you expect it to look like? Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and add areference  image that illustrates what you are expecting to get.

Comment: Is this a ripped character from Fortnite: https://www.epicgames.com/fortnite/en-US/patch-notes/v4-1, https://lezisell.deviantart.com/art/Fortnite-Thanos-XPS-ONLY-744161135?? Uncool..

Comment: @JaroslavJerrynoNovotny Im curious why is this UNCOOL? I dont play that game, Is this a model that was not supposed to be given away?

Comment: I'm guessing that since it is an asset ripped from a modern-day game, it'll follow some sort of PBR node setup; which can be reinforced by the fact that you mentioned there is a metalness map. I'd recommend watching this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4H5W6C_Mbck as will provide you with some background knowledge over what to do with PBR setups.

Comment: @icYou520 pretty sure it was not supposed to be given away and was just ripped from the game - else it would be available to download from the unreal asset store (like the free characters from Paragon that was discontinued). Don't tell me you don't know why theft is uncool..

Comment: @JaroslavJerrynoNovotny That was my question, I dont play video games, I never realized you can "RIP" character models from video games. Never knew that was a thing.

Comment: @icYou520 aah, I see now, I didn't know you didn't know, sorry:) Yeah, some people go great lengths to unpack models from games. Fortunately its almost always for non-profit use or game mods. But some people put them in portfolios claiming as own or there is even porn made with them.. Worst is when part of the game is cloned and modified for chinese markets and makes profit there.

Answer (score 2):

To start off, download the weighted normals add-on: https://blenderartists.org/uploads/default/original/4X/b/b/6/bb60fd3ddf118fca056b6840acae494f6e57a06b.zip

To give credit where it is due, I obtained everything I use in this demonstration from here: https://pr0f3550rz00m.deviantart.com/art/Thanos-Fortnite-3D-Model-744104114

Now, for each individual mesh piece: (make sure you're in object mode) Select the mesh, press <kbd>SPACE</kbd> and search for `weighted normals` and hit <kbd>ENTER</kbd>. Then, with the mesh still selected press <kbd>SPACE</kbd> again and search for `Clear Custom Split Normals Data` and then hit <kbd>ENTER</kbd>

**Note** do not apply the split normals to his face, as it will cause hard edges on an organic surface, which we do not want. After applying that to mesh, we can begin the node setup!

**Also** you'll need to remove all of the parts which relate to his skin, as they should not be treated as hard surface objects either.

For point of reference, the metalness and specularity maps contain information as follows:

R = Ambient Occlusion

G = Unknown

B = Roughness/ Metalness/ Emission

A = No alpha channels are included

### Helmet and Torso Node Setup

---

This is the general setup for the helmet and the torso piece, however; the gauntlet and face have an extra part to them as they both seem to contain a part that emits light.

**Make sure that textures not affecting the colour are set to `non-colour data`**

[image: Node setu[p]

### Face Node Setup

---

[image: Face Setup]

You could just use the original diffuse map to control the emission value, I just happened to make a duplicate of it in this example.

### Gauntlet Node Setup

---

[image: Gauntlet Node Setup]

*This time I just use the original diffuse map for the colour input.*

Just in case it isn't clear from the image, the blue channel from the metallic map is controlling the factorial of the mix node.

---

And here is an example of the final result:

[image: Final]

Hope this helps.

Comment: "To give credit where it is due" - pls don't give credit to people that steal assets from games.. Giving credit to the thief does not make your usage of the asset ok.

Comment: Fair statement and I understand that taking people's hard work in modelling and texturing isn't the most ethical thing to do, but similarly; the time and effort that goes into creating code that can grab the various data associated with models requires a similar amount of effort and time. Not to mention having to create a system to dump the files and then decrypt the files specific to the game's engine, so that standard programs can read them. Put simply, I gave credit from where I obtained the assets from, showing that I was not the one who put the effort into extracting it.